# How to retrieve the date from my table in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle database and my table has a column called load date which has entries like this :

```
12/11/2014 1:50:23 PM
12/11/2014 1:53:03 PM
3/17/2015  7:23:53 AM
11/29/2014 3:53:20 AM
```

I want to retrieve the records from my table for 17th march. How do I do that?

Comment: `select * from your_table where trunc(your_column) = TO_DATE('17-Mar-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')` . `TRUNC()` nullifies the time to `00:00`. Provided the column is a `DATE` column

Comment: @Pkr check my answer and do not forget to accept It as correct answer If It will work for you. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this:

> TRUNC without parameter removes hours, minutes and seconds from a DATE

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE TRUNC(LoadDate) = TO_DATE('03-17-2015', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
```

---

Or you can use following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE LoadDate >= TO_DATE('2015-03-17', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND LoadDate <  TO_DATE('2015-03-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using TRUNC on a column in your database has the unfortunate effect that the TRUNC function must be applied to the particular field (LOAD_DATE, in this case) on every row in your table. This tends to be very slow. Instead, I suggest using a BETWEEN test, as in the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
  WHERE LOAD_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('17-MAR-2015 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                      AND TO_DATE('17-MAR-2015 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

It may works for you :

```
 select * from   YourTable where (extract(day  from LoadDate) =17 ) and (extract(month   from LoadDate) =3);
```